# Issue's with Modal images becoming background image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm fairly new to this all together so if there is an answer already out there, I apologize.I'm having major issues with the modal images  on my page. For some reason when the modal image is launched it ends up being in the background of the site and the text and other content ends up being on top.

Here is the link to view: http://demottdrapery.com/project/expirement/

Below is my current coding for this page.

```
    <table class="dylan">
  <tr>
  <div class="goku">
    <td class="talks">
        <img id="myImg" src="http://demottdrapery.com/wp- 
   content/uploads/2017/12/MASTER-BED-1- 
   1.jpg"style="width:100%;height:auto;"class="visual">

          </td>
          </div>
          <div class="goku">
    <td class="talks">
        <img id="myImg" src="http://demottdrapery.com/wp- 
   content/uploads/2017/12/DINING-ROOM-1-1.jpg"style="width:100%; 
    height:auto;"class="visual">   
    </td>
    </div>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
    </div>
    </tr>
    </table>

      <script>
    // create references to the modal...
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    // to all images
     var images = document.getElementsByClassName('visual');
      // the image in the modal
     var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");

     // Go through all of the images with our custom class
     for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      var img = images[i];
      // and attach our click listener for this image.
      img.onclick = function (evt) {
    console.log(evt);
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
     }
    }

     // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
     window.onclick = function(event) {
       if (event.target == modal) {
           modal.style.display = "none";
       }
    }
    </script>

    <style>
        #myImg {
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
     .modal {
     display: none;
     /* Hidden by default */
     position: fixed ;
     /* Stay in place */
     z-index:100;
     /* Sit on top */
     padding-top: 100px;
      /* Location of the box */
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
     /* Full width */
     height: 100%;
     /* Full height */
     overflow: hidden;
     /* Enable scroll if needed */
     background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
     /* Fallback color */
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
     /* Black w/ opacity */
    }

    .modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
   }

       @keyframes zoom {
       from {
         transform: scale(0)
        }
         to {
          transform: scale(1)
       }
    }

       @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
      .modal-content {
      width: 100%;
     }
     .dylan{
        margin: 50px auto 0;
      width:100%;
      border-spacing:20px 0;   
     }
      .talks{
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: hidden;
        padding-top:45%;
    }
    .visual{
        position:absolute;
      top: 0;
      left:0;
      background-position: center center;
       background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
     .goku{
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: hidden;
  }
  }
```

Comment: Try putting you `<div id="myModal" class="modal">` just before the closing `</body>`. You should always place popups like models on the root level of the body so that they are not nested inside any other DOM elements

Comment: Also, your HTML markup is invalid. You cannot place `div` as an immediate child of a `tr` only `td` is allowed. Your `div class="goku"` is being removed from the table by the browser in the rendered output and could affect styles or javascript you have written.

Answer (score 0):

Any z-index applied to elements within that parent element will only apply to other elements within that parent. All the elements within the parent will be stacked accordingly, then that entire element will be put behind the text as specified by its stack order.

Move the modal div above the rest of the page content. You may need to rewrite your js after this I am not great at JS.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
</div>

<div data-vc-full-width="true" data-vc-full-width-init="true" data-vc-stretch-content="true" class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid vc_custom_1474396432392 vc_row-has-fill vc_row-o-equal-height vc_row-o-content-middle vc_row-flex" style="position: relative; left: -15px; box-sizing: border-box; width: 1116px;">

...

<table class="dylan">
  <tr>
    <div class="goku">
      <td class="talks">
        <img id="myImg" src="http://demottdrapery.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/MASTER-BED-1-1.jpg" style="width:100%;height:auto;"class="visual">
      </td>
    </div>
    <div class="goku">
      <td class="talks">
        <img id="myImg" src="http://demottdrapery.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/DINING-ROOM-1-1.jpg" style="width:100%; height:auto;"class="visual">   
      </td>
    </div>
  </tr>
</table>
```